# My credit card company has stopped charging me interest. Shall I inform them?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-card

I have a credit card with ~£5,000 balance and the interest rate is 27% APR.

A few months ago I was checked my transactions online, looking for the latest interest charge, but I couldn't find it. So I called them and the rep said that they couldn't find any interest charge for the previous month, nor the last several months. I joking said something like "long may it continue" and we end the call in a friendly and courteous manner. So I expecting a large interest charge the next month, but again there was none.

I have been using it quite regularly, and paying 10% of the balance every month (as I have for the last few years).

Shall I inform them that they still haven't charged me any interest ? It's been 6 month now since the last charge.

Comment: What is your interest rate supposed to be?  What is your current balance on your credit card?  Are you still making new purchases using this card?

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica Yes, as I say in the question I still use it. I didn't change my usage at all. There is ~£5,000 balance and the interest rate is 27% APR.

Comment: Your monthly statements should have _some_ mention of interest. If they explicitly say "Interest: £0.00" I think they'd struggle to come at you later trying to get it back...

Answer (score 10):

If I were you, I would not inform them again.  You've already called and informed them once.  Perhaps you are in the midst of some sort of hidden "no interest" promotional period, and the interest could start accruing at any time.

Instead, I would pay off that balance in full as soon as possible, before they start charging interest again.

I hope you realize how incredibly oppressive a 27% interest rate is.  In order to get rid of that debt, stop using the card and pay as much as you can possibly squeeze out of your budget to get rid of that debt as fast as possible.  Once the debt is completely eliminated, resolve to only charge to credit cards what you can pay right away to avoid any interest charges.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I do. Actually, the reason I called them in the first place was because I was arranging a debt consolidation loan which I obtains already. So I could pay it all off right now.

Comment: @PSellaz That's great.  I'd pay that thing off ASAP, then work on paying off the new loan as soon as you can.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use this time to pay down the interest bearing balance? That would be my recommendation. It's not your job to quality control their system but you should fully expect they will figure it out and charge any applicable interest.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but it's good advice.